# Stretch or contract a curve in 2D

Tags: curves, transformational-geometry

I want to correct visual odometry (VO) trajectory with GPS and assign each point of the VO curve a computed GPS coordinate.

**Data I have:** I have a curve that represents the VO trajectory (blue in the picture) - this trajectory was calculated via some computer vision algorithms and I know coordinates of every point of this curve. Then I only have two GPS coordinates - the start and finish of the "ground truth" (ie. I don't know exactly the whole red curve - I only picture it for clarity).

**What I need:** How can I correct (stretch/contract etc.) the blue VO curve so that it nears the red ground truth curve as close as possible?

Here is the situation (GPS start is the same as VO start):
[image: visual odometry and gps ground truth]

Comment: I just learned my problem is called "Similarity transformation" so I edited the tags accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Without a model of the data error or the VO process, you cannot (reasonably) do so. It's tempting to say "let's pick a group that acts on the plane, and find an element that sends the start and VO finish to the start and GPS finish, and apply that to the whole curve". (A typical group to pick might be "translations and rotations" or "projective transformations" or "orientation preserving similarity transformations".) But there's no reason to believe that the transformation you get by doing so has anything to do with the ground truth, and indeed, there's good reason to suspect otherwise: an error in the VO computation near the start (e.g., a slight directional error) leads to a much greater finish-error than does the same error near the end of tracking. Hence in ascribing corrections, you need to weight them accordingly to avoid bias.

I'm going to go ahead and answer the question you almost asked by telling you how to find the *similarity transform* that does what you need. Let's call the start $S$, the finish $F$, and the GPS finish $G$.

Let
$$
u = atan2( (F-S)_y, (F-S)_x) - atan2( (G-S)_y, (G-S)_x).
$$
That should be the angle between the rays $SG$ and $SF$. (Subscripts indicate which coordinate you're using.)

Let $s = \sin u; c = \cos u$. Let 
$$
R = \begin{bmatrix} c & s \\ -s & c \end{bmatrix}.
$$
which rotates by an angle $-u$.

Then the function you want is 
$$
f(
\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end {bmatrix}) = S + \frac{\|G-S \|}{\|F-S\|}R (\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end {bmatrix} - S).
$$
That (in a coordinate system where $S$ is the origin), rotates the ray $SF$ to point in the direction $SG$, and then scales it to have the proper length. It's therefore the unique orientation-preserving similarity transform sending $S$ to $S$ and $F$ to $G$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What does M stand for in your final formula? Is your final formula actually the same as if I would correct the drift with FG vector that would be scaled by the "actual length" of the VO curve (scale from 0 to 1 considering 1 being the full length of the VO curve)? This would also map S to S and F to G, right?

Comment: How does your scaling work? Similarity transformation probably scales by the vector distance of the scaled point from the (coordinate system) origin, right? Such scaling may not be ideal for my VO trajectory because the ideal drift accumulates with VO length (or rather with the number of VO points but lets assume the points are spaced equally) so I guess it would be better to scale by a the fraction of the length of the VO curve.

Comment: $M$ should have been "$R$" --- I'll edit. Is my answer the same as "proportional adjustment"? No --- that's a shearing operation, but mine is angle preserving. You might consider a text case where $S$ is the origin, $F = (1, 1)$ and $G = (0, 1)$. Your map ends up being $(x, y) \mapsto (x+y, y)$; mine is rotate-by-45 and scale by $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: As for "it'd be better to scale by the length of ...", if that's what you wanted, you should have said so. But don't go changing the question after you've asked it --- that's just rude.

Comment: I did not know about the scaling issue before and no, I will not change the question to reflect it. I am just realizing things afterwards... Anyways you set a direction for me which I greatly appreciate! :)